# Stream video files from s3 bucket

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, nestjs

I have some difficulties to stream video files from aws s3 bucket. I have implemented video stream in nest.js, however is not working as expected. (I am using `@aws-sdk/client-s3` library)

1. I can't seek a video.
2. video total length is only show, when full video is viewed.

Here is my code:

```
  async getVideoFromStorage(@Query('path') pathToStorage: string) {
    if (!pathToStorage) {
      throw new NotFoundException('Please provide a path');
    }
    const videoFromStorage = await this.client.send(
      new GetObjectCommand({
        Bucket: 'bucket',
        Key: pathToStorage,
      }),
    );

    if (!videoFromStorage) {
      throw new NotFoundException('File not found');
    }

    const uintArray = await videoFromStorage.Body.transformToByteArray();

    return new StreamableFile(uintArray, {
      type: 'video/webm',
      length: videoFromStorage.ContentLength,
    });
  }
```

Comment: This is not streaming since you download the entire file first. Why do you want to implement the streaming yourself instead of using a library for that? S3 supports byte range fetches to e.g. fetch the first N bytes with the file header which might include metadata about the runtime of the media file, etc. Seeking might also be performed via byte range fetches since you may not need the first half of the file if you want to watch only from the second half onwards. But implementing this from scratch will not be trivial I would assume, especially if you want to handle different file formats.

Comment: If this is your backend code you should not be downloading the file anyway, instead you should create a presigned url for S3 / CloudFront and send that one to the client. The client should then use e.g. an HTML5 `<video>` tag to display the video, that does support streaming out of the box.

Comment: @luk2302 so my backend should create presigned url for each video that user click on?

Comment: That is one option, yes. Another option are various setups with CloudFront.

Comment: @luk2302 I did how you said with presigned url, now I can seek video, but total video duration still showed after a whole video is loaded. You can see here https://codepen.io/EivydasV/pen/ZEjWomx

Comment: It might be that your webm file does not have a duration in its header!? This is no longer related to your code or S3 but more about the specific file (format and codex, etc.) and I am not familiar enough with those to help you unfortunately. If you use https://superuser.com/a/1497131/464605 `ffprobe -show_data -hide_banner Downloads/eRqdXMmaqcQLHrAp5ozHQ_1920x1080.webm` you get `Duration: N/A, start: -0.007000, bitrate: N/A` which looks like the file is missing some metadata.

Comment: @luk2302 yes you are right Duration header N/A, however I try to view my video on the different browser firefox and there video duration is shown, before I used Brave browser, But in firefox I can't seek video, when I try to seek video, video just freezes, but I can see that timestamp is going, the same happens, when I downloaded video to my pc duration is shown, but on seek it freezes video. However problem is now clrear my video files get corrupted, when I transform them with `fluent-ffmpeg`

Comment: @luk2302 I don't know how much do you know about `fluent-ffmpeg`, but I have created question on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74941395/fluent-ffmpeg-output-stream-closed-when-using-aws-s3. That what causing those weird issues I be leave.  There I end up just ignoring that error `Output stream closed`, because it happens on `end` event, so thought it will be fine, but now I see that isn't fine

Comment: Also I see another potential problem in the future with presigned url. For example take youtube, when you chnage video quality it starts playing where you left and with presigned url I don't think that is possible, because when you will change video quality it will start from 0

Comment: The changing quality should not be a problem: the video player knows the old timestamp, can fetch the header for the new file and then seek to the previous timestamp in the new file.

Comment: The webm file linked does not have a duration or even size in the seek head entry of the EBML, meaning the player will necessarily need to download the entire file to discover these values.  You need to provide these values in the container for the player to seek correctly.  How you do so is entirely dependent on the tool creating the video file, and has nothing to do with how you serve up the content.

Comment: @AnonCoward I don't think so, because I tried to convert same video with `ffmpeg` and then upload to s3 and everything worked flawlessly I can seek video and I can see the total video duration, so the problem is really in `fluent-ffmpeg` that messes my video. You can see problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74941395/fluent-ffmpeg-output-stream-closed-when-using-aws-s3

Answer (score 0):

For an ideal streaming setup you need to transcode your files for Adaptive Bit rate Resolution, like converting the original file into 360p, 480p etc. Then you can package / transmux and use that to stream. That way videos will be downloaded in chunks and played.
Otherwise you are downloading the whole file.
Note: you can use ffmpeg on ec2 to transcode your files. Or use aws Mediaconvert. Then stream.